# Run async operation after class construction C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I created a lock object wrapper (class) that use semaphoreSlim(1) as a lock mechanism for my manager (class) operations.
My manager class contains a lock that i send on construction of the new wrapper class, then i use Await on this wrapper class lock (that actually awaits the lock i sent it on construction). and release it on Dispose (the purpose of the wrapper class is to automatically lock and release, lock upon construction, and release upon dispose).

I Use this pattern for the new lock wrapper i built:

```
//_syncLock is a class that used as member lock to use in my operations as async lock.
using (OperationSyncLockWrapper syncLock = new OperationSyncLockWrapper(_syncLock))
{
    await syncLock.Wait(); //I wish to avoid this line and run it automatically
    await SomeAsyncOperation(parameter1);
}
```

Since i cannot use async/await in a constructor method. Is there another way to await on the new object i just created - on class construction or right after ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, unfortunately, you cant split object construction into co-routines. Hence, cant use `async` on constructor.

You can consider exposing your wrapper API with a factory pattern.

```
using (var syncLock = await OperationSyncLockWrapperFactory.GetInstanceAsync(_syncLock))
{
    await SomeAsyncOperation(parameter1);
}
```

You can `await` in the factory method:

```
public static class OperationSyncLockWrapperFactory {

    public static async Task<OperationSyncLockWrapper> GetInstaceAsync(YourSyncLockClass _syncLock)
    {
        OperationSyncLockWrapper syncLock = new OperationSyncLockWrapper(_syncLock);
        await syncLock.Wait();

        return syncLock;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Thanks Stephen for the suggestion. Agree that with extension methods, using the API would be much clearer. Based on your suggestion, it would be something like this:

```
using (var syncLock = await _syncLock.GetSyncLockWrapperInstanceAsync())
{
    await SomeAsyncOperation(parameter1);
}
```

And the extension class:

```
public static class YourSyncLockClassExtensions {

    public static async Task<OperationSyncLockWrapper> GetSyncLockWrapperInstanceAsync
                                                        (this YourSyncLockClass _syncLock)
    {
        OperationSyncLockWrapper syncLock = new OperationSyncLockWrapper(_syncLock);
        await syncLock.Wait();

        return syncLock;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: When you expose an async API to other developers with your library, generally, you dont want to capture the `SynchronizationContext` when you `await` inside the library - this is also a best practice. In your case too, now that you `await` in the factory method, you would want to consider not to capture the `SynchronizationContext`.

In the factory method:

```
await syncLock.Wait().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: This would be even cleaner if the factory method were an extension method for the `_syncLock` type.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Thanks. Updated answer based on your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The only way to `await` currently is to actually use that keyword as well as `async` modifier on the method declaration which translates your method into co-routines.

You can't simulate co-routine creation without those keywords to produce the same behavior they provide.